# Setting jqGrid RowNum dynamically

Tags: jqgrid

I am facing an issue when using [jqGrids](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start).

I have a jqGrid whose rowNum is set to 10. I have this in my JavaScript code:

```
rowNum: 10,
height: 160,
width: 742,
shrinkToFit: false,
sortname: 'CreditRequestID',
sortorder: "asc",
viewrecords: true,
```

Now my source for populating the grid is in the model. So say my model.SearchResults has 25 records. So the first time this grid is loaded I am populating 10 records. I have a more.. Link, which when clicked, should add 10 more records to the grid so total displayed is 20.

My grid will also execute the following controller code:

```
public ActionResult RecentActivityResultsGridEventHandler(string sidx, string sord,
                                                          int page, int rows)
{
    int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
    int pageSize = rows;
    int totalRecords = 20;
    int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
    var JSONData = {//code to read the records from model.SearchResults 
                     //and assign column by column to grid
                   }
}
```

How can increment `rowNum` of the grid by 10 dynamically each time when the user clicks the `more..` link?

Answer (score 13):

If all you need to do is increment the rowNum property, then you can use the getGridParam and setGridParam functions:

```
function incrementRowNum(gridName){
    var grid = $('#'+gridName);
    var currentValue = grid.getGridParam('rowNum');
    grid.setGridParam({rowNum:currentValue+10});
}
```

Comment: One must trigger "reloadGrid" after setting "rowNum".