# jQGrid how to correctly turn off paging

Tags: jqgrid

So in order to do that i need to remove `pager:` value in grid declaration and i need to set maximum rows number to `rowNum: 100000000,`, according with that post [How to show all rows in the jqGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237096/how-to-show-all-rows-in-the-jqgrid)

But what about json which i need to return from server,

```
var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page = page,
                records = totalRecords,

                rows = ...
            }
```

Which values better to assign to `page` and `totalRecords` in that case? 
Should i better pass them as zeroes or it is doesn't mater at all in such case?

**UPDATE:**

I think i would set `records` to total number rows that will go to jason, and `page` and `total` i will set to `1`

What do you think? Anymore i can do  to correctly turn off jqGrid paging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's correct to place `page` and `total` to 1 and `records` to the total number rows. The setting `rowNum: 100000000` seems to too large. If you will really post back from the server `100000000` rows of data the user will probably never see the grid. It seems enough to set `rowNum` to `10000`.

If you don't use tree grid you can use **local paging of data**. In the case you need set just `loadonce:true`. In the case the server should post all the data to the client and just ignore the input `rows` parameter. Look at the demo which uses local data paging of 5000 rows of data [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/5000paged.htm) and compare the results with the same demo without local data paging [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/5000.htm). The difference in the performance will show why I recommend you to use local data paging instead of scrolling the same data in the browser.

Comment: ok i will decrease the rowNum, by the way could you have look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765741/jqgrid-reload-grid-after-save-inline-button-click