# Is it possible to set paging false in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

i have added pager:"#pager" but now i don't think that i need paging so i just need a add button(+), son can anybody tell me how to set paging false without removing the whole bar..just remove pagging

```
 grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
        { resize: false, add: false, search: false, del: false, refresh: false, edit: false, alerttext: 'Please select one user' }

    ).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager',
        { title: "Add New users", buttonicon: "ui-icon ui-icon-plus", onClickButton: showNewUsersModal, position: "First", caption: "" });
```

Comment: it may be a stupid question ;(

Comment: Read this : http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager#properties ;) There is no stupid question. You have to set pgbuttons, pginput to false to do what you want.

Comment: i read it but i don't want to remove the bar just want to remove the paging so the (+) add button still appears.. i need that button there

Comment: It doesn't remove the bar. It just removes some inputs. If you can create a JsFiddle of what of you have done, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: yes but things like <(Page of 1)> are still there i just want to remove those things

Comment: Add `viewrecords : false, pgtext : ""` in your jqGrid options. It should be enough

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read this : [pager properties](http://trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apager#properties).

You have to set pgbuttons, pginput to false to do what you want.

```
grid = $("#your_table").jqGrid({
   // all your options
   pgbuttons : false,
   viewrecords : false,
   pgtext : "",
   pginput : false
});
grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    { resize: false, add: false, search: false, del: false, refresh: false, edit: false,    alerttext: 'Please select one user' }

).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager',
    { title: "Add New users", buttonicon: "ui-icon ui-icon-plus", onClickButton: showNewUsersModal, position: "First", caption: "" });
```

Comment: This just hides the buttons, but pagination still exist.

Comment: @jstuardo, look at what wanted R K Sharma. ;) For what you need, maybe look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6782965/1788704.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish this without having to use the `navButtonAdd` method.  Simply set the `pgbuttons`, `pginput` properties to `false` and `pgtext` to `""`.  Configure the `navGrid` properties as you would otherwise.

Testing used free-jqgrid. https://github.com/free-jqgrid

```
$('#grid_id').jqGrid({
    url:'url',
    editurl:'edit_url',
    height: 'auto',
    shrinkToFit: true,
    width: 280,
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'POST',
    postData:{
        ...
    },
    colNames:[
        ...
    ],
    colModel:[
        ...
    ],
    sortname: 'idsort',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Caption',
    pager: true,
    rowNum: 10000,
    pgbuttons: false,
    pginput: false,
    pgtext: ""
});
$('#grid_id').jqGrid("navGrid", 
    { 
        position:"center", 
        iconsOverText: true, 
        addtext: "Add", 
        edit: false, 
        deltext: "Delete", 
        search: false, 
        refreshtext: "Reload", 
        view: false 
    }
);
```