# jqGrid subGrid stops opening after scroll

Tags: jqgrid, local, subgrid

I have a grid (version 4.1.1) using a subGrid.  I'm using loadonce: true and scroll: 1.  When the grid first loads, I can open subGrids with no problem, **until** I scroll the main grid down to the point where it loads more data.  After that, no subgrid will open or close.  If I click on the plus icon, I see the "Loading...", but nothing happens.  I can't even close the subGrids that were previously opened.

Here is my grid definition:

```
$("#grid_sites").jqGrid({
url:'getgridxmlsites.php',
      postData: {detailid: function() {return $('#hdnDetailId').val(); }},
datatype: 'xml',
height: 260,
width: 832,
shrinkToFit: false,
caption:'',
colNames :['studydetailid', 'Site', 'Name', 'Status', 'Location'],
colModel :[
   {name:'detailid',     index:'detailid', width:0, hidden: true },
   {name:'sitenumber',   index:'sitenumber',    width:60,   align:'right'},
   {name:'name',         index:'name',      width:230},
   {name:'status',       index:'status',        width:110,  align:'center'},
         {name:'location',       index:'location',  width:74}
       ],
 pager:'pager_sites',
 scroll: 1,
 viewrecords:true,
 sortable:true,
 sortname: 'sitenumber',
 autowidth: true,
 pgbuttons: false,
 loadonce: true,
//      gridview: true, // Cannot be used when using subGrid.
 onSelectRow: function(id){ gridRowSelect(id) },
 subGrid: true,
 subGridUrl: 'getgridxmldatabysite.php',
 subgridtype: 'xml',
 subGridModel: [{
        name: ['Owner', 'Phone', 'Status'],
        width: [120, 100, 100],
        align: ['left', 'left', 'left'],
        params: ['detailid']
    }],
  subGridOptions: { reloadOnExpand : false }
});
```

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 3):

I am experiencing a similar problem.  It looks like the addSubGrid function in jqgrid is adding a click event to toggle the subgrid to every row in the table (not just the ones that were just loaded).

This was causing the new rows to behave fine but the first set to rapidly expand and then collapse (two click handlers).  When another set of data got loaded the first set of rows worked fine (although they'd expand, collapse, and expand again) but the second set no longer worked.

I got kind of lost in the combination of addJSON and addSubGrid when trying to figure out if I was missing some of the row metadata in the JSON.  For now I just modified the line:

```
$(ts.rows[i].cells[pos]).bind('click', function(e) {
```

to:

```
$(ts.rows[i].cells[pos]).unbind('click');
$(ts.rows[i].cells[pos]).bind('click', function(e) {
```

and everything seems to work as expected.  This is for version 4.2.0 of jqGrid.  I'm still not sure if this is a bug, a configuration problem, or a data problem but at least I'm working again.

Comment: This still seems to be happening in jqgrid 4.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Typical the `"Loading..."` means an error in the processing of the server response. I recommend you to use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and to start your page in the debugger. For example you can use Developer Tools of Internet Explorer. Do do this you should press <kbd>F12</kbd> to start Developer Tools, then choose "Script" and click on "Start debugging" button. Either the page will be stopped on error or you will be see some additional information in the "Colsole" on the right pane.

I personally not use `scroll: 1` option because of complexity of the data processing and different known bugs or problems. It seems to me that you use incompatible combination of parameters. I would recommended you to remove either `loadonce: true` or `scroll: 1` parameter.

Comment: The "Loading..." is the loadtext which always appears whenever a server request is being made.  I turned scroll:1 off and it works, but now I have to use paging on the grid.  We have always used the scroll:1 on the grids before with no problem and really like it's behavior, but this is the first time we are using a subgrid.

For now, since I have a tight timeline, I will use paging.  I'll try to debug a little bit later.

Thanks.

Comment: @David Davis: You are welcome! The problem is that "Loading..." will be hide *at the end* of the response processing. So if an error or an exception take place the "Loading..." still be seen. The exact place where the exception take place you can find during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration, you do not set rowNum. So I believe jqgrid will use the default rowNum which is 20. This causes the scrolling issue due to the click binding issue mentioned by Robert Simmons.

Another way to fix this issue without having to change the jqgrid code is to set the rowNum to -1. This will just get all rows, which should be fine because you are using local data. This fix may not work in previous versions to 4.6.0 however. (See [How to show all rows in the jqGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237096/how-to-show-all-rows-in-the-jqgrid) for more info on setting rowNum to -1). In versions prior to 4.6.0 I think the main solution was to just set rowNum to a large number.