# how to disable rownum property of jqgrid table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

the rownum property of jqgrid by default takes 20.
now i have json data of length 50. now after loading it shows 
        View 1 - 20 of 50
once i reach  20 by scrolling down it brings the next 20 records and shows
        View 1 - 4 of 50
and hence forth.
i want to display View 1 - 50 of 50
this i can do by setting rowNum:data.length(). but the data is coming as part of ajax call . hence rowNum property gets set before data is actually fetched.
setting the rowNum after grid is loaded does not serve the purpose.
As i have fetched all the data at one shot i don't want this repeated ajax call. hence i want to disable the rowNum property.
plz help...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1557987/480659

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [options page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) on the jqGrid wiki says:

> Set this parameter to -1 (unlimited) to disable this checking.

It is, however, struck out so may no longer be correct (or may have never been correct). Seems like it's worth a try, though.

Comment: Sorry! i tried with 1 not -1. with -1 it is working perfectly. thanks for your help.

Comment: @DebaprasadJana: Setting of -1 is not good because of possible implementation problems depend on other options which you use. You can just use some large enough value like `rowNum: 1000` or `rowNum: 10000`. It is safe and work perfectly in any combination with other jqGrid options and any server side implementation.