# Issue with local data in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm having a weird issue with jqGrid. What I noticed is if I have an array of data with just one item in it, it displays nothing.(checked the html elements no data there). Have 2 items in the array it displays only the first item. basically it seems to be dropping off the last item in the array.

datatype is "local" and I have a array of data that is being used for the data field. I never noticed the issue before because I usually have a lot of data not just 1 or 2 items. nothing else special about it.

Comment: Something I forgot to mention this only happens with rowNum -1;

Comment: The workaround I found for now is setting rowNum to the array length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned the code used `rowNum: -1` which is no longer supported by jqGrid. For now the easiest solution is to set `rowNum` to a large number.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237096/how-to-show-all-rows-in-the-jqgrid/1557987#1557987) for more information and other potential workarounds.

Comment: +1 from me. Especially in case of the usage of *local* data only positive values of `rowNum` are allowed.

Comment: Well I tested this with setting it as you said and the getDataIds doesn't work correctly. I did upgrade to 4.3.3 and that seemed to fix it. Was running 4.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Setting the size to the array size almost fixed it completely. The issue was still the getDataIds method. Was running 4.3.2 upgrading to 4.3.3 completely fixed it.