# jqgrid changing the default rowNum size

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid to show data in tabular format, using JSP and servlet.

```
rowList: [],        // disable page size dropdown
pgbuttons: false,     // disable page control like next, back button
pgtext: null,         // disable pager text like 'Page 0 of 10'
viewrecords: false ,
```

I have used the above code to disable the `navigation of pages`, but i want that all the data from database should be diplayed in the table, but default value of `rowNum` is `20`. so the problem is that when there are more then `20` records in the database, then only `20` records are shown in the grid, and there is no way to see other records, so how should i change the value according to the values in the database(or remove the default value of 20)?

[**Note:** I can set the value of `rowNum` to some big value like `100000`, but I want to know is there any proper way of doing it?}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set `rowNum` to some large enough value like `rowNum: 10000`. It's an option of jqGrid. If you want to change the default value of some jqGrid option you can set property of `$.jgrid.defaults` before you create the grid. For example

```
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    rowNum: 10000,
    pgbuttons: false,
    viewrecords: false
});
```

You can see the most default values of jqGrid options in [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.base.js#L667-L771) of source code of jqGrid.

Comment: yes, i can set the value large value, but i just wanted to know if there is any way to remove the default value. any way thanks again

Comment: @Bhushan: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. The code of jqGrid just set `rowNum` explicitly to 20 (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.base.js#L671)). So you can only overwrite the value to some another value by changing `$.jgrid.defaults` (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.base.js#L771)). Moreover **jqGrid just use the value of `rowNum`** (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.base.js#L1366) for example). So *it must be defined to a numeric value*.

Comment: @Bhushan: So it has no sense "to remove the default value".

Answer (score 0):

```
rowNum: -1 will show all the data. For more details see this answer.
```

[How to show all rows in the jqGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237096/how-to-show-all-rows-in-the-jqgrid)